# Prevent mouse-off-element fade if message box is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a feedback button for my website, when hovering over it the text box will expand and user can enter text then submit their feedback.

The issue is the mouse fade out. When you move your mouse away from the element, it fades away, even if the user has clicked in the text area to start writing a message. I think most people would move their mouse before typing, so this is annoying.

Any one know a way to prevent mouse away fade if the text-box is clicked.. jQuery/js/css? Below is the jQuery, HTML & CSS I'm using now:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  menuPosition = $('#fl_menu').position().top;
  FloatMenu();
  $fl_menu.hover(
    function() { //mouse over
      $fl_menu_label.fadeTo($menu_fade_speed, 1);
      $fl_menu_menu.fadeIn($menu_fade_speed);
    },
    function() { //mouse out
      $fl_menu_label.fadeTo($menu_fade_speed, $closed_menu_opacity);
      $fl_menu_menu.fadeOut($menu_fade_speed);
    }
  );
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#fl_menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 183px;
  height: 50px;
}
#fl_menu .label {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-family: "Arial Black", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 7px;
}
#fl_menu .menu {
  display: none;
}
#fl_menu .menu .menu_item {
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #bbb;
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#fl_menu .menu a.menu_item:hover {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
.menu-submit {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #808080;
  color: #bbb;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.message.menu-message {
  resize: vertical;
  max-height: 100px;
}
.menu-submit {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fl_menu">
  <div class="label menu_item">Feedback?</div>
  <div class="menu">
    <form id="feedback-form" class="comments-form contact-form menu_item" action="https://formspree.io/me@gmail.com" method="POST">
      <textarea class="message menu-message" type="text" name="comment" placeholder="Enter text.."></textarea>
      <input name="submit" type="submit" class="menu-submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final result:

HTML:

```
<div id="fl_menu">
    <div class="label menu_item">Feedback?</div>
    <div class="menu feedback-menu">
        <form id="feedback-form" class="comments-form contact-form menu_item" action="https://formspree.io/me@gmail.com" method="POST">
        <textarea class="message menu-message feedback-menu" type="text" name="comment" placeholder="Enter feedback.."></textarea>
    <img id="FeedbackClose" src="./img/close.png" />
        <button id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" style="border: 0; background: transparent; margin-right: -12px; margin-top: -2px;" class="menu-submit feedback-menu"><img src="./img/blue-submit-button.png" width="100" height="auto" alt="submit" /></button>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
body{margin:0px; padding:0px;}
#fl_menu{position:absolute; top:40px; left:0px; z-index:9999; width:183px; height:50px;}
#fl_menu .label{padding-left:19px; padding-right: 19px; line-height:50px; font-family:"Verdana", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); color:#fff; letter-spacing:7px;}
#fl_menu .menu{display:none;}
#fl_menu .menu .menu_item{display:inline-block; background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); color:#bbb; border-top:1px solid #333; padding:10px 20px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; text-decoration:none;}
#fl_menu .menu a.menu_item:hover{background:#333; color:#fff;}
.menu-submit {display:inline-block; background:#808080; color:#bbb; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; text-decoration:none;}
.message.menu-message { resize: vertical; max-height: 100px; }
.menu-submit { float: right; }
#FeedbackClose { float: left; width: 22px; height: 22px; margin-top: 5px; position: relative; }
#FeedbackClose:hover { transform: scale(1.1); -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in; transition-timing-function: ease-in;-webkit-transition: width 2s;}
#submit:hover { transform: scale(1.05); -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in; transition-timing-function: ease-in;-webkit-transition: width 2s;}
#submit { outline: none;  -moz-outline-style: none; }
```

js

```
// Commonly used DOM variables
$wrapper = $("#fl_menu");
$textarea = $wrapper.find("textarea");
$form = $wrapper.find('.menu');
$fl_menu_menu=$("#fl_menu .menu");
// Initalize hasClicked flag to false
var hasClickedTextarea = false;


// When the textarea is clicked tip the flag
$textarea.on('click', function()
{
    hasClickedTextarea = true;
});
// Default fade in and fade out speed to 500
var FADE_SPEED = 100;


// Mouse in and mouse out callback fn's
// Only fade out if the textarea has not been clicked
$wrapper.hover(
  function()
  {
    $form.fadeIn(FADE_SPEED);
  },
  function()
  {
    if(!hasClickedTextarea)
    {
      $form.fadeOut(FADE_SPEED);
    }
  }
);
$(document).bind('click', function(e) {
    if(!$(e.target).is('.feedback-menu')) {
    hasClickedTextarea = false; 
    $form.fadeOut(FADE_SPEED);
  }
});

//config Float options
$float_speed=1500; //milliseconds
$float_easing="easeOutQuint";

//cache vars
$fl_menu=$("#fl_menu");
$fl_menu_menu=$("#fl_menu .menu");
$fl_menu_label=$("#fl_menu .label");

$(window).load(function() {
    menuPosition=$('#fl_menu').position().top;
    FloatMenu();
    $fl_menu.hover(
        function(){ //mouse over
            $fl_menu_label.fadeTo($menu_fade_speed, 1);
            $fl_menu_menu.fadeIn($menu_fade_speed);
        },
        function(){ //mouse out
            $fl_menu_label.fadeTo($menu_fade_speed, $closed_menu_opacity);
            $fl_menu_menu.fadeOut($menu_fade_speed);
        }
    );
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
    FloatMenu();
});

function FloatMenu(){
    var scrollAmount=$(document).scrollTop();
    var newPosition=menuPosition+scrollAmount;
    if($(window).height()<$fl_menu.height()+$fl_menu_menu.height()){
        $fl_menu.css("top",menuPosition);
    } else {
        $fl_menu.stop().animate({top: newPosition}, $float_speed, $float_easing);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/37htuwe6/1/

Javasript:

```
// Commonly used DOM variables
$wrapper = $("#fl_menu");
$textarea = $wrapper.find("textarea");
$form = $wrapper.find('.menu');


// Initalize hasClickedTextarea flag to false
var hasClickedTextarea = false;


// When the textarea is clicked tip the flag
$textarea.on('click', function()
{
  hasClickedTextarea = true;
});


// Default fade in and fade out speed to 500
var FADE_SPEED = 500;


// Mouse in and mouse out callback fn's
// Only fade out if the textarea has not been clicked
$wrapper.hover(
  function()
  {
    $form.fadeIn(FADE_SPEED);
  },
  function()
  {
    if(!hasClickedTextarea)
    {
      $form.fadeOut(FADE_SPEED);
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: @Danny Can you throw it in a fiddle??

Comment: Yeah, but for some reason jfiddle can't interpret the jQuery, maybe I set it wrong? Anyways, here's the exact coding from my site, I altered the email for obvious reasons lol.

https://jsfiddle.net/37htuwe6/

Comment: @Danny finally got the fiddle workin I'll have somethin for ya in a sec!

Comment: You're the man, thank you! Been working on it too, trying to get that if(!hasClicked) to work in some way :)

Comment: @Danny Updated w/ Fiddle!

Comment: Much deserved check-mark to this answer, thank you sir!! Gonna add a click function to the doc to hide the feedback box in case the user changes their mind.. This is great!!

Comment: @Danny Happy to help!

Comment: Ok.. Added this to the end of the script you were nice enough to create, and it's done!

$(document).bind('click', function(e) {
  if(!$(e.target).is('.feedback-menu')) {
      $form.fadeOut(FADE_SPEED);
  }
});

Comment: @Danny Ahhhh so now you have an event for when they click outside the menu to close it up. Very nice! If it were me from a UX point of view I'd add a close button adjacent to that submit button or an X somewhere near that top left or right that triggers the same close event when it's clicked. That way no one's left guessing, "how do I close this thing"!

Comment: Yeah, but noticed it required click after the first time in order to fade, if you go back again.. So ended up with adding just this to the end of your script as a final result. Although, now that you mention it, my OCD may end up demanding a "close" button lol

$(document).bind('click', function(e) {
 if(!$(e.target).is('.feedback-menu')) {
 hasClickedTextarea = false; 
 $form.fadeOut(FADE_SPEED);
  }
});